# Ubuntu 14.10 copy dialog gone

Tags: unity, dialog

I am facing the problem, that my copy dialog is gone while performing a large copying operation. The miniature progres bar is still visible in the launcher icon and shows that the action is still going on.
This happened several times in the past weeks and I don't know how to fix it.
Selecting "show copy dialog" does not have any effect...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please go with terminal copy command to avoid such issues,

Command can be found in the below URL :
http://linuxcommand.org/lts0050.php#cp

Comment: that's not really answering ACB's question. They're still able to copy, so I'm not sure how suggesting using `cp` really helps. If you're going to suggest this route then I'd at least include some reference to the options to increase verbosity and show what's happening as, without the option, the user has even less visibility as to what's going on which is precisely the issue ACB wants to address.